# Modsecurity finds no geo data for IP

Tags: apache, apache2, owasp, mod-security

I want to block every country except mine, so I downloaded the GeoLite2 database and added it in the crs-setup.conf file. Under *-=[ Block Countries ]=-* I also added every country code for testing.

This did not work and after trying multiple alternative "country blocking" rules I looked into the debug log and saw that the rule itself was working, but it wasn't finding any geo data for the IP:

```
Recipe: Invoking rule 72bef6b0; [file "/etc/modsecurity/rules/REQUEST-910-IP-REPUTATION.conf"] [line "75"] [id "910100"].
Rule 72bef6b0: SecRule "TX:HIGH_RISK_COUNTRY_CODES" "!@rx ^$" "phase:2,log,auditlog,id:910100,drop,t:none,msg:'Client IP is from a HIGH Risk Country Location',logdata:%{MATCHED_VAR},tag:application-multi,tag:language-multi,tag:platform-multi,tag:attack-reputation-ip,tag:paranoia-level/1,tag:OWASP_CRS,ver:OWASP_CRS/3.3.2,severity:CRITICAL,chain"
Transformation completed in 8 usec.
Executing operator "!rx" with param "^$" against TX:high_risk_country_codes.
Target value: "AD AE AF AG AI AL AM AO AQ AR AS AT AU AW AX AZ BA BB BD BE BF BG BH BI BJ BL BM BN BO BQ BR BS BT BV BW BY BZ CA CC CD CF CG CH CI CK CL CM CN CO CR CU CV CW CX CY CZ DE DJ DK DM DO DZ EC EE EG EH ER ES ET FI FJ FK FM FO FR GA GB GD GE GF GG GH GI GL GM GN GP GQ GR GS GT GU GW GY HK HM HN HR HT HU ID IE IL IM IN IO IQ IR IS IT JE JM JO JP KE KG KH KI KM KN KP KR KW KY KZ LA LB LC LI LK LR LS LT LU LV LY MA MC MD ME MF MG MH MK ML MM MN MO MP MQ MR MS MT MU MV MW MX MY MZ NA NC NE NF NG NI NL NO NP NR NU NZ OM PA PE PF PG PH PK PL PM PN PR PS PT PW PY QA RE RO RS RU RW SA SB SC SD SE SG SH SI SJ SK SL SM SN SO SR SS ST SV SX SY SZ TC TD TF TG TH TJ TK TL TM TN TO TR TT TV TW TZ UA UG UM US UY UZ VA VC VE VG VI VN VU WF WS YE YT ZA ZM ZW"
Operator completed in 20 usec.
Rule returned 1.
Match -> mode NEXT_RULE.
Recipe: Invoking rule 72eb4298; [file "/etc/modsecurity/rules/REQUEST-910-IP-REPUTATION.conf"] [line "77"].
Rule 72eb4298: SecRule "TX:REAL_IP" "@geoLookup " "chain"
Transformation completed in 2 usec.
Executing operator "geoLookup" with param "" against TX:real_ip.
Target value: "###.##.#.###"
GEO: Looking up "###.##.#.###".
GEO: Using address "###.##.#.###" (0x########). ##########
No geo data for "###.##.#.###" (country -4431872).
Operator completed in 10205 usec.
Rule returned 0.
```

However the IP is in the database as I checked it with geoip2 in Python and it returned the correct country for said IP.

Is there anything obvious I missed?

Comment: Are you sure you have downloaded old, legacy, format of GeoIP database? ModSecurity doesn't support new GeoIP2 format.

Comment: OWASP Core Rule Set developer emphazer has a great script for converting the new style MaxMind database files into the old style .dat files, which ModSecurity can then use. Maybe it will help. You can find it here:
https://github.com/emphazer/GeoIP_convert-v2-v1

Comment: Thanks, I knew it would be something stupid like that. For some reason I thought I had ModSecurity 3, that's why I tried to use GeoLite2 instead of legacy. It works now perfectly! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ModSecurity does NOT support new GeoIP2 format of GeoIP database so old, legacy, format need to be used.